# Slot filter with Vuejs and ElementUi

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui, vue-data-tables

I have table where a column in there uses `slot-scope` and I can't get that column data into filters option.

## Code

`Component filter input`

```
<el-input v-model="filters[0].value" placeholder="Type to filter"></el-input>
```

`component HTML`

> issue part is commented

```
<data-tables class="bg-white shadow-sm"
    :data="transits"
    :filters="filters"
    style="width: 100%">
    <el-table-column prop="name" label="Name" sortable="custom"></el-table-column>
    <el-table-column label="Barcode" sortable="custom"> <!-- can't get this data into filter -->
        <template slot-scope="scope">
            <div v-if="scope.row.barcode.serial_number">
                {{scope.row.barcode.serial_number}}
            </div>
            <template v-else>
                {{scope.row.barcode.u_serial_number}}
            </template>
        </template>
    </el-table-column>
</data-tables>
```

`Component Script`

> I gave more column sample in filters function so you can understand the logic behind `element-ui` table

```
<script>
export default {
    props: ['user'],
    name: "adminOuterTransits",
    data() {
        return {
            transits: [],
            filters: [
                {
                    value: '',
                    prop: ['formNo', // works (belongs to transit table)
                            'receiptNo', // works (belongs to transit table)
                            'description', // works (belongs to transit table)
                            'fob', // works (belongs to transit table)
                            'gudang', // works (belongs to transit table)
                            'ship_via', // works (belongs to transit table)
                            'sent_at', // works (belongs to transit table)
                            'received_at', // works (belongs to transit table)
                            'barcode'], // DOESN'T WORK (IT'S RELATIONSHIP DATA "barcode.serial_number")
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    // rest of it....
}
</script>
```

**Any idea how to include barcodes data into filter input?**

Comment: you'd like to apply filter for `barcode` column based on rendered text? And I don't find `el-table` provides one props=`filters` from [Element-UI guide](https://element.eleme.cn/#/en-US/component/table#table-attributes). But `el-table-column` provides.

Comment: @Sphinx hi, `you'd like to apply filter for barcode column based on rendered text?` Yes. `And I don't find el-table provides one props=filters` it's in table `:filters="filters"`. would you mind share your solution as an answer so I can see where i did mistake?

Comment: from the answer of @dreijintjens, I realized you used the extension `vue-data-table`, not the default table component `el-table` in Element-UI.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is better to mention the extension on element-ui next time https://www.njleonzhang.com/vue-data-tables/#/en-us/ ;)

But to get to your question the prop you want to filter on `barcode` you have to write your own `filterFn` as there is no prop defined on the `el-table-column` so the prop is `undefined` https://www.njleonzhang.com/vue-data-tables/#/en-us/filter?id=leverage-filterfn

Also take a look on the diagram that is provided https://www.njleonzhang.com/vue-data-tables/#/en-us/filter?id=principle-of-data-tables39-filter

---

If you don't want to use `vue-data-tables` you could also work with a `computed` dataset as done in the example on the element-ui page: https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#table-with-custom-header

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer but i couldn't make it happen based on your shared links.

Comment: Hi, if you could set up a sample in codepen I will look at it.